# Is there a uniform way operating file system on different os with C++?

Tags: c++, operating-system

A lot of script languages such as python, ruby and perl, then all have a uniform way operating file system of different os. When switched to c++, I find it difficult to write os-independent  code.

For example, I found on Linux, with findfirst, findnext, you can search file names in a given pattern, but on Windows, there are _findfirst _findnext in io.h and CFileFind, which should I use on Windows, and why there isn't a uniform way operating file system.

More important, where should I reference if I want to know the os-independent components of C++ and C?

Comment: C++14 is aiming to have a `<filesystem>` header in TR2, but there's always `boost::filesystem`, which it's based off of.

Comment: You can also consider using POSIX functions, which are fairly portable.

Comment: apart from what's mentioned above, you can also use the Qt library

Comment: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is an excellent reference for the standard C++ and C libraries.